# "Votes Cast" according to my profile is different from "Votes Cast" on my summary

Tags: bug, feature-request, voting, profile-page

I was surprised to find out just now that I had earned the `Civic Duty` badge. The badge requirement is to vote 300 times.

However, when looking at my profile, I see that the `Votes Cast` votes tab shows only 267 votes.

Perhaps I voted on questions that were later deleted, which removed the vote from my `Votes Cast` page but still counted toward the badge.

Any thoughts on why I earned the badge but can only see 267 votes that I cast?

**Edit**: On my `Summary` page, it shows I have voted 300 times (which I see before). However, my `Votes Cast` page has a different tally. See the screenshots attached.

### Summary Page

[image: Summary Page]

### Votes Page

[image: Votes profile page]

Comment: I see a full 300 on the Summary tab -- 253 up, 47 down.  I can't see your Votes tab, can you provide a screenshot? (Redact anything you need to.)

Comment: I didn't notice the summary tab. It shows the full 300 as well. I guess my question is now more about the Votes page and why it doesn't show the same results as the summary.

Comment: In particular, when I select the `downvote` sub-tab, it shows I only voted down 19 times, not 47. It makes a lot more sense now that the votes tab doesn't show questions/answers that have been deleted.

Comment: That does make sense.

Comment: This has been asked in SO meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109032/civic-duty-badge-at-299-votes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `votes` tab only shows details for votes to questions and answers still in existance. That is, deleted questions/answers are removed from the `votes tab` and also change the tally on that page.

However, the Stack Exchange database still keeps track of your votes on deleted items and counts that toward the total votes needed for a badge. It also shows this accurate total on the summary profile page.

I think that the `votes` page should show a correct total, perhaps distinguishing between available and deleted votes.